# Point with a residue $k$ maps to the point with the same residue

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

This is a problem II 2.15b from Hartshorne.

> If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of schemes over $k$ and if $p\in X$ with a residue field $k$, then $f(p)$ also has a residue field $k$.

My attempt:

> I know that there is an induced $k$-map between $k(f(p))$ and $k(p)=k$, but I don't believe that it implies that $k(f(p))=k$. For me $k$-map means that there is a commutative triangle, i.e. $g:k\rightarrow k(f(p))\rightarrow k$ and $h:k\rightarrow k$ s.t. $g=h$, but unless $h$ is an isomorphism I don't see how it follows that $k(f(p))=k$. I'm probably missing something very simple.

EDIT:
As @Roland suggests, there is an abuse of notation in the sense that actually we have to assume that $k\rightarrow k(p)=k$ is be an isomorphism.

> Is there a counterexample to the statement without taking into account the abuse of notation? I'm still suspicious about the remark: is there any source which claims that there is such an abuse of notation? I'm not sure that I saw this in Hartshorne.

Comment: There is an abuse of notation here. When we say that $p\in X$ has a residue field $k$, this actually means that $k\to k(p)$ is an isomorphism and considered as an identity. So $k\to k(f(p))\to k(p)$ is an isomorphism (because $f$ is a $k$-morphism) and so in particular, $k(f(p))\to k(p)$ is onto. As @Asura Path said, it is into as any morphism between fields, so $k(f(p))\to k(p)$ is an isomorphism and so is $k\to k(f(p))$.

Comment: @Roland thank you, I edited my question accordingly

Comment: This is a very common abuse of notation because technically a residue field is almost never strictly equal to the base field. Think about $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[X]/(X)$ (the local field of the affine line at the origin). Strictly speaking, they are not equals, but we identify them through the map $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}[X]\to \mathbb{C}[X]/(X)$. So abuse it and the problem II 2.15b from Hartshorne is true (and very often used).

Comment: Thank you. Your comment answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Any map from $k(f(p))\rightarrow k$ must have  a kernel, and that kernel must be an ideal, and in a field, the only ideal is $(0)$.  Therefore the  kernel is $(0)$, so the map is injective.

It's also surjective, because the identity $k(p)\rightarrow  k(p)$ factors through it.

That makes it an isomorphism.

Comment: how do we know that $k(p)\rightarrow k(p)$ is identity ?

Comment: Minor nitpick: if $k$ is a field, then $k$ is also an ideal of $k$. The only ideals are $(0)$ and $k$. (However, what you say is correct if you instead say "that the kernel must be a non-zero ideal, as $1$ goes to $1$ and $1\neq 0$ in a field.)